# Atom text editor terminal is not working properly

Tags: django, terminal, atom-editor

I am practicing Django in atom text editor and install Platformio-ide-terminal package but after installation when I click to the + sign on the bottom left it is showing me blank console

my expected result is console with some directories but it is showing me blank space with a blinking cursor

Comment: Does your .atom folder still exist? What other packages so you have installed? Can you be specific about the + sign,?

Comment: Which version of Atom do you use? Did it work at some point, e.g. in an older version of Atom?

Comment: currently, I am using1.39.1 for ATOM and 2.9.3 for platformio-ide-terminal, and yes it was working with the previous version

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem. To do so, click on the checkmark on the left side of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Update, August 20, 2019**

The issue was fixed in [Atom v1.40.1](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.40.1)

**Old answer**

The said package is currently not working with Atom v1.39, since it includes a major update for the underlying Electron framework.

You can try and rebuild the package's native modules. To do so, run `apm rebuild` inside the `~/.atom/packages/platformio-ide-terminal` folder.

If that doesn't work, one workaround is to downgrade Atom to v1.38.x and wait for a fix.

For futher infos on the problem, you can follow this [discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/cannot-install-platformio-ide-terminal-2-9-1-on-atom/67012/13) or subscribe to the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/19705).

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall the Platformio de terminal it works in my case.